# How spark-shell or Zepellin notebook set HiveContext to SparkSession?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

Does anyone know why I can access to an existing hive table from spark-shell or zepelling notebook doing this

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from hive_table")
```

But when I submit a spark jar with a spark object created this way,

```
     val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Yet another spark app")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 18)
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
    .config("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    .getOrCreate()
```

I got this

> Table or view not found

What I really want is to learn, understand, what the shell and the notebooks are doing for us in order to provide hive context to the SparkSession.

Comment: You didn't call `enableHiveSupport()`

Comment: Thank you, OMG that easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When working with Hive, one must instantiate SparkSession with Hive support

You need to call `enableHiveSupport()` on the session builder